# How to load images for Resource folder into an NSArray in iOS?

Tags: ios5

I have 20 images in my resource folder and I want to add all these images into an single array in order to access into the next screen, I have tried various combinations but not able to get the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folloe these steps >>>>

1) Take an array in AppDelegate class

NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

2) Iterate a loop

for (int i = 1;  i <= 20; i++) {

```
    NSString *strImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",i];
    [arr addObject:strImageName];

}
```

3) Now you can access this MutableArray anywhere in your project.

To add image over image view do the following >>>

UIImageView *imageView;

imageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:[appDel.arr objectAtIndex:iTemp]];

```
if (iTemp < 19) {
    iTemp ++;
}
```

4) To change the count ie. iTemp use the step 3 inside button event.

Try this out this will definately help you.